# Migration not importing into image fields

Tags: media, database, migrations

I'm working on a Migration class to import from a depreciated WordPress plugin and everything's just about there -- everything succeeds when importing and there aren't any errors; taking the SQL from Migrate UI and plugging it into MySQL yields the data table I need.

However, the images aren't importing at all. None of the relevant tables -- file_managed, field_data_field_photo -- are updating.

All images are already in /sites/default/files/wp-content/uploads/. The paths are stored like "2012/10/image.jpg" (I.e., year/month/filename) in the source database.

Hugely grateful for any help.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 *  Migrating WordTour WordPress plugin to OpenMusicFestival on Drupal.
 */

abstract class WordTourMigration extends Migration {
  public function __construct() {
    // Always call the parent constructor first for basic setup
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class ArtistMigration extends WordTourMigration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    //Set up other database

    Database::addConnectionInfo('wp', 'default', array(
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'database' => 'db_wp',
          'username' => 'user',
          'password' => 'pass',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'prefix' => '',
        ));

    $this->description = t('Migrate the artists!');

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
        array(
          'artist_id' => array(
                           'type' => 'int',
                           'length' => 7,
                           'not null' => TRUE,
                           'description' => 'Artist ID',
                          )
        ),
        MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
      );

    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'wp')
           ->select('artists', 'a');
    $query->join('attachment', 'at', 'a.artist_id = at.attachment_target_id');
    $query->join('attachment', 'att', 'a.artist_id = att.attachment_target_id');
    $query->join('postmeta', 'pm', 'pm.post_id = att.attachment_type_id');
    $query->fields('a',
              array(
                  'artist_id',
                  'artist_name',
                  'artist_publish_date',
                  'artist_bio',
                  'artist_record_company',
                  'artist_social_links',
              )
            );
    $query->fields('pm', array('meta_value'));
    //$query->addField('pm', 'meta_value', 'photo');
    $query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT at.attachment_info)', 'genres'); //Pull in genres.
    $query->condition('at.attachment_target', 'artist');
    $query->condition('at.attachment_type', 'genre');
    $query->condition('att.attachment_type', 'thumbnail');
    $query->condition('pm.meta_key', '_wp_attached_file');
    $query->groupBy('a.artist_id');


    // Create a MigrateSource object, which manages retrieving the input data.
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, array(), NULL, array('map_joinable' => FALSE));

    // Set up our destination
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('artist', array('text_format' => 'full_html'));

    // Assign mappings TO destination fields FROM source fields.
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'artist_name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('uid')
         ->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('changed', 'artist_publish_date');
    $this->addFieldMapping('status')
         ->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('promote', '')
         ->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('sticky', '')
         ->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision')
         ->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('log')
         ->defaultValue('Migrated to Drupal 7 from WordPress.');
    $this->addFieldMapping('comment')
         ->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('body', 'artist_bio')
          ->arguments(array('format' => 'full_html'))
    $this->addFieldMapping('created', 'artist_publish_date');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_labels', 'artist_record_company')
          ->separator(', ')
          ->arguments(array('create_term' => true));
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo', 'meta_value');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:source_dir')
         ->defaultValue('/Users/aendrew/Sites/test/sites/default/files/wp-content/uploads/');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:preserve_files')
         ->defaultValue(true);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:destination_file', 'meta_value');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:file_replace')
         ->defaultValue(MigrateFile::FILE_EXISTS_REUSE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:alt', 'artist_name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_photo:title', 'artist_name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_links', 'artist_social_links')
         ->description('See prepare()'); //Needs to be unserialized
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_genres', 'genres')
          ->separator(',')
          ->arguments(array('create_term' => true));
  }

  public function prepareRow($row) {
    watchdog('migrate', 'Filename is ' . $row->meta_value); // This is reporting correctly.
  }

  public function prepare(stdClass $node, stdClass $row) {
    //Set up the links
    $links = unserialize($row->artist_social_links);
    $empty = 'a:10:{s:13:"artist_flickr";s:0:"";s:14:"artist_youtube";s:0:"";s:12:"artist_vimeo";s:0:"";s:15:"artist_facebook";s:0:"";s:14:"artist_twitter";s:0:"";s:13:"artist_lastfm";s:0:"";s:14:"artist_myspace";s:0:"";s:15:"artist_bandcamp";s:0:"";s:13:"artist_tumblr";s:0:"";s:19:"artist_reverbnation";s:0:"";}';
    if ($node->field_links[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url'] == $empty) {
      unset($node->field_links);
    } else {
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($links as $site => $link) {
        if (!empty($link)) {
          $site_name = ucfirst(str_replace('artist_', '', $site));
          if ($site_name == "Youtube") $site_name = "YouTube";
          if ($site_name == "Lastfm") $site_name = "Last.fm";
          if ($site_name == "Youtube") $site_name = "YouTube";
          if ($site_name == "Myspace") $site_name = "MySpace";
          $node->field_links[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['title'] = $site_name;
          $node->field_links[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['url'] = urldecode($link);
          $i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently having the same source and destination directory mucks things up — I moved all the images outside of Drupal and suddenly everything works great!